# What happens when you assign a string to a pointer variable?

Tags: c

I don't understand what that ptr variable points at. Is it a single element of the x string? The entire string?

```
int x[]={10,20,30,40,50};
int *ptr=x;
printf("%d",*(ptr+2));
printf("%d",*(ptr)+2);
```

Comment: It points as an int array, which is not a string. And yes, it points at the first element.

Comment: There's no string involved here.

Comment: also `*(ptr + 2)` is better written as `ptr[2]`. `*(ptr) + 2` is not unlike `*(ptr + 0) + 2` which of course is `ptr[0] + 2`. Clear yet?

Comment: "Pointing at the entire string" does not make sense either. A pointer contains an address.

Comment: `int *ptr` means that `ptr` is a pointer to `int`. It points to **an** `int`, so yes, a single element.

Answer (score 1):

This sets up a situation in which `ptr` aliases `x`.

[image: x and ptr are aliased.]

For example `ptr[2] == x[2] == *(x + 2) == 30`. However, `x` and `ptr` are not the same object in the C compiler; specifically, the compiler knows the size of `x`, `sizeof x = sizeof(int) * 5`, and not, `sizeof ptr = sizeof(int *)`. Also, the type of `x` decays to `constant pointer to int` and the type of `ptr` is `pointer to int`; this means `ptr++` is okay, but it doesn't make sense to do `x++`.

Answer (score 0):

The output is:-
30
12
`ptr` is a pointer pointing to first element of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer points to a memory address. When declared and initialized as `int *ptr=x;`, `ptr` is assigned the memory address where the first element of `x` starts in memory. So if `x` consists of three 4-byte integers which contain the decimal values 10, 20, 30 and the lowest byte address of the first integer begins at address 0x1010, `ptr` would be assigned the value 0x1010, and the memory addresses occupied by `x` would look like

```
Addr |1010|1011|1012|1013|1014|1015|1016|1017|1018|1019|101A|101B|
     +====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+
Val  | 0A | 00 | 00 | 00 | 14 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 1E | 00 | 00 | 00 |
     +====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+
```

(All addresses and values above are shown in hexadecimal)

The above assumes a "little-endian" architecture, such as the Intel x86, where the low-order byte of a multibyte integer is stored in the low-order address. (Other orderings of multibyte integers in memory are used on other architectures but I won't address them here).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

A pointer points to *an address*. To convince yourself, you could print the different addresses of the different element of the array by using the `%p` flag in printf.

```
printf("%p\n", ptr[0]);
printf("%p\n", ptr[1]);
printf("%p\n", ptr[2]);
```

Comment: A pointer *is* an address. It points to object which has that address, whatever that object might be. (It might itself be a pointer, which is why these semantics are important.)

Comment: You'd have to use `&ptr[x]` for this to be valid. Right now your code is just printing `int`s as pointers.

Comment: @rici pointer is not the address. It is an object which holds the reference to another object. We simplyfying call something like this `&a` the pointer but in the fact is the reference

Comment: @P__J__: if this question were tagged C++, I'd give you that but I think in C, it's just hair-splitting. There are no reference types in C. "The unary & operator yields the address of its operand." (Sect. 6.5.3.2p3). It is generally expected that you can round-trip from a pointer to a sufficiently large integer and back to a pointer (of the same type): "The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment." (6.3.2.3p5, footnote)

Comment: It's true that there might not be an integer type large enough and such implementations exist(ed). But in any event, in C, the distinction between reference and address is very fine. In C++, as I said, the distinction is real and important.